# LINQ 2 XML: Simple Input, Brain Fart With Solution

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

So i have this simple XML text:

```
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <error>
    <domain>GData</domain>
    <code>InvalidRequestUriException</code>
    <internalReason>You must specify at least one metric</internalReason>
  </error>
</errors>
```

What the simplest way to extract the value of the internalReason element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace when finding descendants. For example:

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005";
var reason = xml.Descendants(ns + "internalReason").First().Value;
```

Or:

```
 var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
 XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005";
 var reason = xml.Elements(ns + "error").First()
                 .Elements(ns + "internalReason").First().Value;
```

(I'm not keen on using query expressions when they don't really provide any extra value.)

You might also want to split it up and use `FirstOrDefault` so that you can check whether the elements you're asking for are present or not.

Comment: Yup, it was the namespace. Thanks.